# Cross DB SQL Trigger Epic Failure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, triggers

I have the below SQL Trigger on a SQL 2005 box that is *supposed* to help me replicate certain Person Info to another database to be used for Reporting and various other things as a reference.

I have 1 DB named Connect which is where the current app manipulates the Person Data on tblPerson.  I have another DB, on same physical box, named MATRIX where a new app manipulates it's Data.  I am trying to build a Table in MATRIX called tblIdentificationMap that simply stores all of the various ID's we have from the different apps in house.

When I enable this Trigger and try to update tblPerson I get the following error --> `Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Procedure tblPersonIDMap_OnUpdate, Line 15
Invalid object name 'MATRIX.dbo.tblIndentificationMap'.`

This is my UPDATE statement -->

```
`  use Connect
  update tblPerson
  set MiddleName = 'Fakey'
  where PersonID = 258243`
```

And this is my Trigger -->

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[tblPersonIDMap_OnUpdate] 


ON  [dbo].[tblPerson] 
   AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;





UPDATE MATRIX.dbo.tblIndentificationMap
        SET     m.PersonID = i.PersonID
                ,m.FirstName = i.FirstName
                ,m.MiddleName = i.MiddleName
                ,m.LastName = i.LastName

    FROM MATRIX.dbo.tblIdentificationMap m, inserted i, deleted d
    WHERE d.PersonID = m.PersonID
END
```

Comment: Your update statement looks wrong - you refer to tables m, i, and d in the 'from', but only specify joins between m and d tables in the 'where', yet you use i to set the new values - I dont know if this would cause the error you are seeing, but it sure looks like a problem.

Comment: Thank you Ray but let me see if I can clarify.  `d` has the old info.  `i` has the new info.  `m` is the table in a different db that I am writing to.  I use `d = m` to make sure I am updating the correct record but I want the data from `i` to be written to `m` as that is the updated info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
UPDATE MATRIX.dbo.tblIndentificationMap
```

with

```
m
```

in the first line. Also in the SET area you don't need the references to m (although I don't think they do any harm, it makes it a smidgeon harder to maintain).

Your SET statement is confused as you're inconsistently referring to the alias and the real name.